# "NETWORK SERVICE" access remote share: Access Denied

Tags: iis, permissions

Service is running as `NETWORK SERVICE` on `Server1`.

I need to connect to a share on another servier: `Server2\Share`.

So I grant `Full Control` to `Server1$` on `Server2\Share`.

Yet I still get an access denied error when I try to open a file in that share.

**Any idea what could be the cause of this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to grant that access in both the share permissions and the NTFS permissions. If you've only allowed access in one, you'll need to do it in the other.